# Dynamic class creation during method calling

Tags: c#, generics

I have an async function which has to be called multiple times but one the input parameters changes with each call.

```
public void ProcesAsyncReq((Class) validatedInputs, string data1, string data2...)
{
  //logic here is to just pass the validatedInputs to the dataprovider ,no changes whatsoever
}
```

while calling from different places, the (Class) changes, it can be example: Employee / Agency / etc
Can we do that somehow ?

What I tried :

```
public class DataStore<T>
        {
            public T data { get; set; }
        }
public void ProcesAsyncReq(string className,string validatedInputs, string data1, string data2...)
{
     DataStore<className> gclass1 = new DataStore<className>(); /*throws error that it is a 
               variable but is used as a type*/
      gclass1.data=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(validatedInputs);
      //logic here is to just pass the validatedInputs to the dataprovider ,no changes whatsoever
}
```

Comment: You can make your method generic as well: `public ProcesAsyncReq<T>(..)`

Comment: @Heinzi can you give an example like any code to refer. i am still in confusion how will i create class instance to send validatedInput data

Comment: I have added a more verbose example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your method generic as well:

```
public void ProcesAsyncReq<T>(string validatedInputs)
{
    DataStore<T> gclass1 = new DataStore<T>();
  
    gclass1.data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(validatedInputs);
    ...
}
```

which you would call as follows:

```
ProcesAsyncReq<Employee>(myStringContainingSerializedEmployee);
```

Comment: thank you. so i believe we can always enter more than one 'T' and adjust accordingly. 
Now my another problem is there is a manager class which is static and singleton and while calling the instance it has to call specific method based on input and that is bigger problem.  anyways lets see . thank you once again